# HTML5 import with sidebar menu

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working at some project, and I have pretty big sidebar menu with many pages, I don't really want to change it all the time at all pages, but also I don't really want to use php include() function.

Well, I went and used html5 import. It actually works, but I have a problem. My index.html is in root folder, but users.html in root/pages folder. So.. When it goes there it imports the same menu as in index.html, but that's wrong. Because link are broken. For example I can't access index.html after that, because I need ../index.html, but instead it's written index.html
This is js I'm using to import file

```
var doc= document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
var text = doc.querySelector('template');
var clone = document.importNode(text.content, true);
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
console.log(dir);
document.querySelector('.sidebar-menu').appendChild(clone);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work from any page if you change the links in your sidebar to absolute paths rather than relative paths. Instead of:

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

use this:

```
<a href="/index.html">Home</a>
```

The exact absolute path may vary depending on if you are using a `/public` folder, etc, but once you get them working once, they will work from any page in your app.

Comment: I was on this page -> http://localhost:8080/projectN_full/index.html
Then when I clicked on the same page at menu bar it gave me -> http://localhost:8080/index.html

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thank you. You helped me to get my answer :)

Comment: @LeoOdishvili no problem, glad it worked. you must have had to use `href="/projectN_full/index.html"`, but then that would work from any page.